# Cocos2d-x lua - interaction with Steam

Tags: lua, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, steam

I'm creating lua game using Cocos2d-x and want to interact with Steam Works (achievements, etc.). Is there any native or extrenal cross-platform libraries (that will work on linux, windows and macOs) specially for this ?